# Sinatra/Ruby new to programming - increasing an integer if a radio button is selected

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I am very new to this and I am trying to do something pretty simple but I am not sure where to begin.  I simply need to increase the "vote" count of a newly posted link from 0 to 10 if a radio button is selected. Here is the complete code that I have so far, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
    require 'sinatra'
    require 'data_mapper'
    require 'haml'
    require 'sinatra/reloader'
    set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

    DataMapper::setup(:default,"sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/example.db")

    class Link
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :title, String
    property :url, Text
    property :bullet, Boolean, :default => false
    property :score, Integer
    property :points, Integer, :default => 0
    property :created_at, Time

    attr_accessor :score

    def calculate_score
      time_elapsed = (Time.now - self.created_at) / 3600
      self.score = ((self.points-1) / (time_elapsed+2)**1.8).real
    end

    def self.all_sorted_desc
      self.all.each { |item| item.calculate_score }.sort { |a,b| a.score <=> b.score}.reverse
    end
  end

  DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!

  get '/' do
    @links = Link.all :order => :id.desc
    haml :index
  end

  get '/hot' do
    @links = Link.all_sorted_desc
    haml :index
  end

  get '/:id' do
    @link = Link.get params[:id]
    haml :index
  end

  post '/' do
    l = Link.new
    l.title = params[:title]
    l.url = params[:url]
    l.bullet = params[:bullet]
    l.created_at = Time.now
    l.save
    redirect back
  end

  put '/:id/vote/:type' do
    l = Link.get params[:id]
    l.points += params[:type].to_i
    l.save
    redirect back
  end

  delete '/:id' do
    l = Link.get params[:id]
    l.destroy
    redirect '/'
  end

  __END__

  @@ layout
  %html
    %head
      %link(rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css")
      %link(rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css")
    %body
      .container
         #main
          .title Learn Sinatra
          .options
          %a{:href => ('/')} New
          |
          %a{:href => ('/hot')} Hot
          = yield

  @@ index
  #links-list
    -@links.each do |l|
      .row
        .span3
          %span.span
            %form{:action => "#{l.id}/vote/1", :method => "post"}
               %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "_method", :value => "put"}
               %input{:type => "submit", :value => "U"}
          %span.points
            #{l.points}
          %span.span
            %form{:action => "#{l.id}/vote/-1", :method => "post"}
              %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "_method", :value=> "put"}
              %input{:type => "submit", :value => "D"}
          .span6
            %span.link-title
              %h3
                %a{:href => (l.url)} #{l.title}

            %span.span
              %form{:action => "#{l.id}", :method => "post"}
                %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "_method", :value=> "delete"}
                %input{:type => "submit", :value => "X"}
  #add-link
    %form{:action => "/", :method => "post"}
      %input{:type => "text", :name => "title", :placeholder => "Title"}
      %input{:type => "text", :name => "url", :placeholder => "Url"}
      %input{:type => "radio", :name => "bullet", :value => "10"}
      %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Submit"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You  basically have to define a route to a function the receives a GET/POST request it should trigger a column update which adds one to the vote count